# .replace() in a string not replacing values

Tags: python

I have converted the binary result of a URL request into a text string, then attempted to replace the instances of '\r' with '' and '\n' with ' ' using the following code:

```
newvar = str(oldvar)
newvar.replace('\r', '')
newvar.replace('\n', ' ')
```

However when the variable newvar is printed to the log and written out to a file it retains the '\r' and '\n'. What am I doing wrong? I'm using the exact syntax suggested and that I had already read online.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`replace` doesn't modify the string, as strings are immutable; it creates a new string, which you need to assign:

```
newvar = newvar.replace('\r, '')
```

Comment: do you mean 'newvar = oldvar.replace('\r, '')'?

Comment: If `oldvar` was already a string, that would also work.

Comment: does it matter that I am converting the binary output from concurrent futures into a string? The variable 'data' contains that output and I am using the code 'data2 = (str(data))
            data2 = data2.replace('\r', '')
            data2 = data2.replace('\n', ' ')' but it isnt replacing the desired characters still

Answer (score 0):

You need of set var to do it:

```
newvar = str(oldvar)
newvar = newvar.replace('\r', '')
newvar = newvar.replace('\n', ' ')
```

Then print:

```
print newvar
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you assign the replacements to the already existing variable like that:

```
newvar = (str(oldvar))
newvar = newvar.replace('\r','')
newvar = newvar.replace('\n','')
```

Answer (score 0):

As with many problems, this boils down to Read The Friendly [Manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

> **str.replace(old, new [, count])**
>
> Return **a copy** <sub>[emphasis mine]</sub> of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

This doesn't change the string. It **returns a copy** of the string, modified.

Comment: i used this initially but it did not work.

Comment: The emphasis was on the **copy** part.

Comment: @jonathonreinhart...i have tried using the exact syntax posted here an in previous answers but it isnt working for me.